# Polygon intersection with LineString in PostGis

Tags: postgis, postgresql, topology

I have a table which contains GPS coordinates at certain times. I created a `LINESTRING` from them ordered from the oldest to newest. 
I also have a `POLYGON` and I would like to determine the subset of my `LINESTRING` which lies inside my polygon. This subset should be only the points from the table - no interpolated points from the linestring. All my geometries have SRID 4326.

I used the `ST_Intersection(myLinestring,myPolygon)`. Because the linestring goes in and out of the polygon multiple times I expect the intersection will be `GEOMETRYCOLLECTION` of multiple `LINESTRINGs` (which correspond to the individual continuous components of the path inside my polygon).

As a quick check to determine the number of components inside I ran: `ST_NumGeometries(ST_Intersection(myLinestring,myPolygon))` but I got some really big number which actually exceeds even the number of coordinates in my table.
When I ran `ST_AsText(ST_Intersection(myLinestring,myPolygon))` I saw that the result is rather a collection of many individual points which lie inside the polygon AND the linestring, but they ARE NOT the samples from my table.

How do I do this right?

**EDIT**: I need to know the connected path components lying inside the polygon, not just the isolated points inside the polygon.

I need to know the inner linestrings so I can determine the total approximate time spent inside the polygon (the time differences of the first and last point of the inner path component summed over all those components would give a precise estimate of the time spent inside the polygon).

Comment: Why not intersecting points vs. polygons then?

Comment: Are the "extra" points lying on the polygon boundary only? That's what i imagine would happen ... with the remaining points being part of your original string. Also, why do you need to string them anyway?

Comment: @gcarrillo: No, I need to know how those points belong to the subsets of the path inside the polygon (the entire connected components of the path inside).

Comment: @martinf: If I make `ST_Intersection(ST_Boundary(myPolygon),myLinestring)` I got those isolated points of intersection, which is correct, so I presume those 'extra' points are from the interior. I need to know the inner linestrings so I can determine the total approximate time spent inside the polygon (the time differences of the first and last point of the inner path component summed over all those components would give a precise estimate of the time spent inside the polygon).

Comment: Please post the new info into the question. I see you've done a little but still you leave more stuff here in the comments than you bother to put into the question!

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, I think @gcarillo has the right idea in his comment.  Rather than building the linestrings before the intersection, determine the points inside the polygon first and then build the linestrings based on sequence groups.

Although it looks a little complex, the following query will achieve this.  I've made some assumptions on the likely structure of your gps points table.

```
-- Build complete lines within the polygon
SELECT startTime, 
       endTime, 
       ST_MakeLine(geom_array) AS line
FROM (
    -- Aggregate the points based on sequence group
    SELECT min(captureTime) AS startTime, 
           max(CaptureTime) AS endTime, 
           array_agg(location) AS geom_array, 
           grp
    FROM (
        -- Intersect the points with a polygon and determine a group for the sequence
        SELECT *, 
               seq - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY captureTime) AS grp
        FROM (
            -- Sequence the points based on time captured
            SELECT captureTime, 
                   location, 
                   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY captureTime) AS seq 
            FROM gpsPoints
            ) orderPoints
        WHERE ST_Intersects(location,ST_MakeEnvelope(1,1,4,4)) --Replace envelope with polygon
        ) pointsInside
    GROUP BY grp
    ) pointGroup;
```

This will pick up points on the boundary as well as inside.  Single unconnected points will be turned into a single point linestring and should be handled or removed from the query results.

**Edit:** Changed the sort column for the grp row_number() to get a better execution plan (one less sort).

Comment: I think you are on the right line (the question could do with a few more details, for sure), but where does seq come from in `seq - ROW_NUMBER()`

Comment: @JohnBarça The seq is calculated in the innermost subquery `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY captureTime) seq`.  I'll edit the answer and try and make it a little clearer

Comment: Oh, yes, so it is, sorry. Are you sure you can't achieve a time grouping with just one call to ROW_NUMBER

Comment: @JohnBarça There are likely to be other ways to do the grouping, but I can't think of a nice method at the moment.  I'll have a think about it and see if there is another way.