# Points of tracklog inside a polygon with a re-enter tolerance

Tags: postgis, postgresql, intersection, linear-referencing, trajectory

I have points in PostGIS that represent GPS coordinates with a timestamp from a tracklog.  I'm interested in selecting the times at which the tracklog entered and exited the polygon with a certain tolerance for reentrance.

I have been able to setup a table of points with an M timestamp from that I can do aggregation and get the tracklog as a linestring, doing an intersection only shows points inside the polygon.  My key problem is that tracklog may re-enter the polygon several times, I would like to have a tolerance setup and if the re-entrance happens before x seconds, consider as if it was not an exit so rather make the exit time the last exit that lasted more than x seconds outside the polygon.

If there are more entrances made after the x seconds tolerance, consider it as an additional enter/exit result.

Is there a simple way to query for this?

I've checked [How to estimate time spent within a location using GPS/timestamp data in PostGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/359096/how-to-estimate-time-spent-within-a-location-using-gps-timestamp-data-in-postgis) but the problem is different and solution not so encouraging.

This other post does something similar but my limited PostGIS experience does not allow me to modify the query for the tolerances
[Polygon intersection with LineString in PostGis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/133548/polygon-intersection-with-linestring-in-postgis?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

A generic query I use to generate AOI trajectory traversal sets:

```
SELECT ply.id AS ply_id, ln.id AS ln_id,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ply.id, ln.id ORDER BY _its.path) AS seg_id,
       _sm, _em,
       _inside::GEOMETRY(LINESTRINGM, <SRID>) AS geom
FROM   <lines> AS ln
JOIN   <polygons> AS ply
  ON   ST_Intersects(ln.geom, ply.geom)
CROSS JOIN LATERAL
       ST_Dump(ST_Intersection(ln.geom, ply.geom)) AS _its
CROSS JOIN LATERAL
       ST_LineLocatePoint(ln.geom, ST_StartPoint(_its.geom)) AS __sfrac
CROSS JOIN LATERAL
       ST_LineLocatePoint(ln.geom, ST_EndPoint(_its.geom)) AS __efrac
CROSS JOIN LATERAL
       ST_M(ST_LineInterpolatePoint(ln.geom, __sfrac)) AS _sm
CROSS JOIN LATERAL
       ST_M(ST_LineInterpolatePoint(ln.geom, __efrac)) AS _em
CROSS JOIN LATERAL
       ST_LineSubstring(ln.geom, __sfrac, __efrac) AS _inside
WHERE  _inside IS NOT NULL
;
```

*`LATERAL JOIN`s are executed in sequence, and each consecutive `LATERAL` expression has access to all previously generated rows and their values - it's a nifty and highly performant way to expand sets of records or values into rows, and to keep certain expressions out of the `SELECT` list.*

Here

- we first `ST_Dump` a (possible) *collection* of `ST_Intersection`s between intersecting `<lines>` and `<polygons>` into individual `LINESTRING`s
- then retrieve the *fractions of line length* (`ST_LineLocatePoint`) on which both the `ST_StartPoint` and `ST_EndPoint` of the `ST_Intersection`s *project onto the trajectory*
- with which we extract the `ST_M` values at the *interpolated point at these fractions* (`ST_LineInterpolatePoint`) - **the enter and exit times `_sm` & `_em`**
- and generate the `ST_LineSubstring`s (`LINESTRINGM`) of the initial `<lines>` that traverse the `<polygons>` - **the `_inside` trajectories**
- we also create a sequence in which these `_inside` trajectories appear along the initial `<lines>` - `seg_id`

---

The merge of consecutive rows and the extension of their exit times is a "*gaps-and-islands*" problem (here slightly altered to include both a `LAG` and `LEAD` check condition for the *flag* column), which is somewhat nasty to write and more so to explain; please hunt down relevant information yourself:

```
SELECT ply_id, ln_id,
       MIN(_sm) AS entry, MAX(_em) AS exit
FROM   (
    SELECT ply_id, ln_id, seg_id,
           _sm, _em, __sgap, __egap, COALESCE((__sgap OR __egap), __egap),
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER wa AS __seq,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER wb AS __cseq
    FROM   (
        SELECT ply_id, ln_id, seg_id,
               _sm, _em,
               _sm - LAG(_em) OVER wa < <threshold> AS __sgap,
               LEAD(_sm) OVER wa - _em < <threshold> AS __egap
        FROM   <above_query>
        WINDOW
             wa AS (PARTITION BY ply_id, ln_id ORDER BY seg_id)
    ) q
    WINDOW
         wa AS (PARTITION BY ply_id, ln_id ORDER BY seg_id),
         wb AS (PARTITION BY ply_id, ln_id, COALESCE((__sgap OR __egap), __egap) ORDER BY seg_id)
) q
GROUP BY
      ply_id, ln_id, (__seq - __cseq)
ORDER BY
      MIN(_sm)
;
```

Wrap in the `<above_query>` or any other expressions that has the same information, and define the `<threshold>` below which you want to have exits merged with the next.

Comment: TX @geozelot, I'm getting the following error with the first query, but not sure which args is referring to:  'SQL Error [XX000]: ERROR: 2nd arg must be smaller then 3rd arg'

Comment: Could you please clarify the meaning of "AOI trajectory traversal sets"?

Comment: @EnriqueVargas it refers to `ST_LineSubstring` - and that `__sfrac` is equal or greater than `__efrac`. First off: naturally, that query **assumes `LINESTRING M`s** coming from `<lines>`. The issue may also happen if a given trajectory returns on itself. A prepared and validated base data set is mandatory for all types of linear reference operarions (well, and all others, too, I guess) - you may need to clear/cluster/filter/sieve out your points before correctly aggregating them into lines.

Comment: And by that I simply mean a set (*of records*) describing the parts of trajectories that overlap (*traverse*) an area of interest (*AOI*) - including their geometries and relevant meta info.

Comment: tx @geozelot, yes the line trajectory has "loops" on itself inside and outside the intersecting geometry, not sure if thats what you mean, this is actually is one of the key things I'm analyzing in the bigger picture, I'm interested in analyzing how much heading changes and the number of such loops inside the polygon, this is the reason I want to first have the part of the line that is inside the polygon.  The second link I shared does this but without having a re-entrance time tolerance.